# Connector types to used to distribute AC mains terminals

Tags: connector

I want to power tens of [these](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/embedded-switch-mode-power-supplies-smps/7541381/) small power supplies. From a single AC mains.

Below I tried to illustrate the powering of these power supplies PSU 1, PSU 2, ect..

[image]

1. But for the case above what are such type of terminal block is called? A terminal block where one does not have to daisy chain and terminals are innerly connected. In other words, what are the yellow blocks above called?
2. For example I found [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/distribution-blocks/2779786/) terminal block under the category called "distribution blocks". But in its [data sheet](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1244/0900766b8124476d.pdf) there are types for earth and neutral but not line. Im totally confused, it doesn't even mention whether the pins are innerly connected. Can I use this for both line or neutral?

Comment: you have not included adequate information in your question .... how much power do the power supplies use?

Comment: it is called `terminal block with shorting links`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to power tens of these small power supplies. From a single AC mains.

The model you have linked is intended for mounting on a PCB. Normally you would use the PCB to handle the power distribution.

> For example I found this terminal block under the category called "distribution blocks". But in its data sheet there are types for earth and neutral but not line.

The block you link to seems to be available in black, blue and green. It seems that the black version is intended for phase, the blue one for neutral and the green one for earth.

http://ecatalogue-export.legrand.com/004854-ip-2x-terminal-block-phase.html

http://ecatalogue-export.legrand.com/004844-ip-2x-terminal-block-neutral.html

http://ecatalogue-export.legrand.com/004834-ip-2x-terminal-block-earth.html

From looking at the pictures and the description as a "distribution terminal block" I am pretty sure that all the terminals are connected but i'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 0):

The supply you link to (TMPM 04215) is meant for PCB mounting with through-hole soldering.

So, none of your connectors are appropriate, and you'd design a power distribution PCB. That might or might not be much cheaper than wiring them individually; I'd argue that every wire that you don't connect manually is potentially two contacts less to be unreliable.

Also, it's explicitly required in the datasheet that you add a fuse on the input of each SMPS. You can't just connect them to one large terminal block unfused!

Then: Why 10s of these in parallel, without individual switches? That's a very expensive solution to get a couple Ampere of +- 15V supply (your supply is spec'ed for 4W output only), instead of having fewer, but stronger supplies (which you could buy from the very same series). If you're concerned about crosstalk, be sure to add sufficient output buffering.

All in all: I wouldn't recommend going for the kind of connector you're after in your application. If you need installation supplies, get some for mounting on DIN rails. These are commonly found in installation boxes, stack side-by-side nicely, and wiring is inherently relatively tidy.

If you need this in a non-installation appliance, go for the PCB mounting. At the specified 77% best-case efficiency each of your 4 W supplies would produce 1 W of heat under load – this means thermal design is easy and you can just pack them relatively close to each other on a PCB; in that case, isolation distances and clearance to avoid creep currents is the dominating design factor, but since these definitely come in a footprint that allows for plenty distance between phase, neutral and the output, that's of no relevant concern, either.

Comment: Its a bit long story but I have to use separate power supplies for channel to channel isolation of each sensor. Sensors should not share the same ground... Im also worried about these PCB mounts. I have no time to design PCB. How about these versions in terms of saftey and mounting?: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/embedded-switch-mode-power-supplies-smps/6641474/ They are twice expensive but maybe better for this applcation. Btw where did you read that fuse is required? Thanks (I couldn't find DIN rail version for dual +-15V)

Comment: Fuses: "input specifications", page 3 of the data sheet. Designing that board might take less time than you think; it's really just sitting down with your favourite EDA software (Kicad? Eagle?) and drawing a couple of lines between matchingly sized footprints, then uploading the resulting file to the boardhouse of your trust (Oshpark? Elecrow? PCB-pool.de?). If the Grounds mustn't be connected, does that mean everything is floating? Why then not simply go for 30V supplies? The fact that these SMPSes are isolated regarding dangerous currents doesn't mean *anything* about the crosstalk at…

Comment: … signal frequencies, so without knowing what sensors we're talking about, I'm not sure you're actually solving a problem: Neither on the side of what the *problem* is, nor on the side of whether you're actually *solving* it.

Comment: Okay let me tell briefly, I need to use many of these sensors https://www.crlsensors.com/prodDocs/sa-107ln.pdf with a ch-ch isolated diff input DAQ board  https://www.mccdaq.com/pdfs/manuals/SC-1608.pdf At the beginning I was gonna use one or two power supply for all sensors, but the manufacturer of the DAQ board told me if I use the same supply then I share sensor grounds and make it single ended and no ch-ch isolation. So the only solution was costly one supply per sensor.  Freq of interest from sensors is less than 3Hz and I will use LPF at the inputs. Thats why need supply for each sensor.

Comment: But if signal integrity at that level is your concern, then you really can't just use an arbitrary smps! These are, by design, sources of significant noise! I'd  much rather recommend going single-ended with a single, well-danpened linear supply than full differential with smps that aren't meant to be measurement sources!

Comment: Yes but single ended is not good for 400 meter long analog transmission. Thats why I will use STP cable with diffe ended daq and the supply noise can be filtered at sensor side.

Comment: That really sounds like a bad idea in multiple aspects. Analog signal over 400m with  a 1000 Ohm source impedance is a bad idea. Centralized low-voltage power supply over 400m is a bad idea. And you're confusing multiple meanings of the word single-ended, I think. The good idea here really is filtering the supply noise at sensor side, though! Since the digitization effort is very benign here, as signal frequencies are inherently very low, I'd recommend digitizing and supplying close to the individual sensors, and only collecting the digital signals centralized.

Comment: But I will filter the signals freq of interst is less than 3Hz.

Comment: Anyway, maybe you'd want to describe the system you're about to build in detail in a new question and ask for feedback. I've never built a seismic observation system :)

Comment: Yes, but your low-frequency error due to ohmic losses in hundreds of meters of cable isn't negligible, either!

Comment: I can calibrate out the DC error due to voltage divider

Comment: Im limited with analog transmission  thats why I dont go for digital transmission. Thats kind of an order. Anyway thank for the suggestions at least I will be careful about the fuses and maybe I but something easy to mount. I dont have time to make PCBs

Comment: Please consider the current that will flow through your 400 m cabling in absolute numbers when terminated with a high-Z DAQ, and relate that to how much induction you expect with a 1A AC power line anywhere in the vicinity of your cable. This is worse than you think.

Comment: You have nonsensical orders, and you have a bad estimate of what takes time and what is worth spending a little time on.

Comment: I agree, I even suggested current loop type but that didnt work hard to convince some stubborn civil engineers

Comment: I would definitely say that for cabling of that length, you'll need signal conditioning hardware at the sensor end. The fact that this hardware isn't anything but an opamp with an output transistor in a configuration that converts sensor voltage to line current does not have to be of any concern to the civil engineers, and that way you'll need a small PCB at every sensor anyway - which is great, because that can contain your supply noise filter, too!

Comment: I mean same sensor have current output type already, I suggested them to try but  they are in hurry and I wont have the responsibility, but I will try again thanks for input